# Vertices sticking out from edges

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to make something similar to the following image:
[image]

I wrote the following code:

```
                \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.8]
%                   \foreach \x in {0,1,2,3}
%                       {
%                           \draw (2*\x,0)--(2*\x+2,0)--(2*\x,1)--cycle;
%                       }
%                   \foreach \x in {0,1,2}
%                       {
%                           \draw (2*\x,1)--(2*\x+2,1)--(2*\x,2)--cycle;
%                       }
%                   \foreach \x in {0,1}
%                       {
%                           \draw (2*\x,2)--(2*\x+2,2)--(2*\x,3)--cycle;
%                       }
%                   \draw (0,3)--(2,3)--(0,4)--cycle;
                    \foreach \x in {0,1,2,3}
                        {
                            \draw (2*\x+2,0)--(2*\x+2,1)--(2*\x,1)--cycle;                          
                            \fill[lightgray] (2*\x+2,0)--(2*\x+2,1)--(2*\x,1)--cycle;
                        }
                    \foreach \x in {0,1,2}
                        {
                            \draw (2*\x+2,1)--(2*\x+2,2)--(2*\x,2)--cycle;
                            \fill[lightgray] (2*\x+2,1)--(2*\x+2,2)--(2*\x,2)--cycle;
                        }
                    \foreach \x in {0,1}
                        {
                            \draw (2*\x+2,2)--(2*\x+2,3)--(2*\x,3)--cycle;
                            \fill[lightgray] (2*\x+2,2)--(2*\x+2,3)--(2*\x,3)--cycle;
                        }
                    \draw (2,3)--(2,4)--(0,4)--cycle;
                    \fill[lightgray] (2,3)--(2,4)--(0,4)--cycle;
                    \draw (0,0)--(10,0)--(0,5)--cycle;
                \end{tikzpicture}
```

but what I got was the following image:
[image]
As circled in red as an example, the vertices are coming out from edges. I would like to know how to fix this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add e.g. `line cap=round,line join=round`.

Answer (score 4):

You can either clip or use an appropriate `line join` (and `line cap`). However, this is also to tell you that your code is perhaps longer than it could be.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,
    pics/triags/.style={code={
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\ncorners}{#1/2-1/2}
    \ifnum\ncorners>0
     \draw[fill=gray!20] foreach \XX in {1,...,\ncorners}
      {foreach \YY in {\XX,...,\ncorners}
     {(\XX-1,\ncorners-\YY+1) -| (\XX,\ncorners-\YY) -- cycle}};
    \fi
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\ncorners}{#1/2}
    \draw (0,\ncorners) |- (\ncorners,0) -- cycle;
    }}]
 \path[x=0.7cm,y=0.5cm] foreach \NN in {2,...,7} 
 {({int(\NN/2)*(int(\NN/2-1/2))+\NN-2},0) pic{triags=\NN}}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]